# Inflating Layout XML to custom LinearLayout creates redundant LinearLayout view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm creating a custom `LinearLayout` component. It's designed to mimic some functionality of a `ListView`, for use in a `ScrollView`, since I can't/shouldn't use a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`.  Let's call it *CustomListView*. Furthermore, I'm creating another custom `LinearLayout` to represent each item in this pseudo-listview, let's call it *NewItemView*.

Anyway, when initialising *NewItemView*, I'm setting it up by inflating a layout XML. The layout XML declares a `LinearLayout` as its root view, and is not dissimilar to layouts like `simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml`.

Overall, what happens is that the main activity has a *CustomListView*. We call `addItem(Item item)` on *CustomListView* to add a new item to the list, which in reality, creates a new *NewItemView*, and populates it with data from the Item class.

I'm inflating in `newListItem.initListItem(Context context)` as so:

```
 ((Activity)getContext())
            .getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, this, true);
```

This actually works!
However, the issue I have is that on inspection with Monitor, there's a redundant `LinearLayout` just sitting around each item in the list. My understanding is that this is generally a bad idea. There's the `LinearLayout` for *CustomListView*, then for each item, there's a `LinearLayout`, with just one child; a `LinearLayout`! That last one contains the actual children.

I expect that it has something to do with the fact that I'm creating a custom component based off LinearLayout, and then inflating a layout with a LinearLayout at it's root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is what the `merge` tag is for. Simply replace your root `LinearLayout` tag with `merge`, and that should do what you need.

See [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html).